# Mahapps Metro Dialog without MetroWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I want to use the dialog's of mahapps.metro in my application. My window is a normal `window`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

not a

```
MetroWindow
```

Inside my button method I wrote this:

```
var metroWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow);
await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Foo", "Bar");
```

I've added an `ThemeManager` inside `App.xaml.cs`

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Tuple<AppTheme, Accent> appStyle = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);

    ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                                ThemeManager.GetAccent("Green"),
                                ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseDark")); // or appStyle.Item1
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

And inside `App.xaml` I added

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Cobalt.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When I execute my programm, I get an

> NullReferenceException

because `metroWindow` == null

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to find a parent `MetroWindow` *anyway*,  so it's unclear why not the `MainWindow` ?

Comment: maybe this https://dragablz.net/2015/05/29/using-mahapps-dialog-boxes-in-a-mvvm-setup/

Comment: The MahApps Dialogs can not be used without a MetroWindow, cause there are some stuff at the style for the window to work with Dialogs.

Comment: @punker76 thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My window is a normal window.

That's your problem. Since `ShowMessageAsync` is an extension method for the `MetroWindow` class, you must have a reference to a `MetroWindow` in order to be able to call it. This means that you must replace your normal window with a `MetroWindow` or use another dialog. The `ShowMessageAsync` method only works with a `MetroWindow`.

The following code tries to cast the `MainWindow` window of your application to a `MetroWindow` but the cast will always fail if the main window is indeed a normal window:

```
var metroWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow);
```

That's why you get a `NullReferenceException`.

> How can I solve this problem?

You must use a MetroWindow. There are no other solutions I am afraid.